# Are there the resources mentioned about finding the general solutions of some first order fully nonlinear PDE examples by method of characteristics?

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations

Although http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Fully_nonlinear_case mentioned that we can solve first order fully nonlinear PDEs (i.e. the first order nonlinear PDEs that the partial derivatives are not bonded linearly) by using the method of characteristics, the website did not make the corresponding examples so that I can understand the detail steps about finding the general solutions of first order fully nonlinear PDEs by using the method of characteristics.

So can anybody find some resources (readable in web should be the best) mentioned the detail steps about finding the general solutions of some first order fully nonlinear PDE examples by using the method of characteristics? This can help me for example to solve [Solve PDE using method of characteristics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276858) perfectly.